# Proof of theorem about direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, direct-sum

> Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ 
> Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$ if and only if each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as $x_1+x_2$, where $x_1 \in W_1$ and $x_2 \in W_2$

**Question 1** 
"If each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as $x_1 + x_2$" = $\forall v \in V \exists ! x_1 \in W_1 \exists ! x_2 \in W_2(v=x_1+x_2)$ 
When $V = W_1 = W_2 = \{0\}$,
$\forall v \in V \exists ! x_1 \in W_1 \exists ! x_2 \in W_2(v=x_1+x_2)$ is true? 
$0 \in V = 0 \in W_1 + 0 \in W_2$ 
$0 \in V = 0 \in W_2 + 0 \in W_1$ 
So I think it is false but it seems true so very confusing.

**Question 2**

> If $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$ and some vector $y \in V$ can be represented as $y = x_1 + x_2 = x_1' + x_2'$, where $x_1, x_1′ \in W_1$ and $x_2, x_2' \in W_2$, then we have $x_1 − x_1′ \in W_1$ and $x_1 − x_1' = x_2 + x_2′ \in W_2$. But since $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$, we have $x_1 = x_1'$ and $x_2 = x_2'$
> Conversely, if each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as
> $x_1 + x_2$, then $V = W_1 + W_2$. Now if $x \in W_1 \cap W_2$ and $x \neq 0$, then we have
> that $x = x + 0$ with $x \in W_1$ and $0 \in W_2$ or $x = 0+x$ with $0 \in W_1$ and $x \in W_2$,
> a contradiction.

<s>I think this part</s>

> If each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as
> $x_1 + x_2$, then $V = W_1 + W_2$.

<s>is wrong because of counterexample:</s> $V=\{0, 1, 2\}, W_1=\{0, 1\}, W_2=\{0, 2\} (3 \notin V)$

I think that part is wrong because
$W_1+W_2=\{x+y:x \in W_1,y \in W_2\}, V=\{v:\forall v \exists ! x_1 \in W_1 \exists ! x_2 \in W_2(v=x_1+x_2)\}$ 
$W_1+W_2 \neq V$ because $W_1+W_2 \nsubseteq V$

Is this correct?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with $0 = 0+0$ in the case of $V=W_1=W_2 = \{0\}$. Your "counterexample" is flawed because $V=\{0,1,2\}, W_1=\{0,1\}, W_2=\{0,2\}$ are not even vector spaces.

Comment: Remember that vector spaces are closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Edited.

Comment: in order to have intuition about the direct sum, you may think about the following setting.$X=\{ (a,b): a,b \in \mathbb R\}=\mathbb R^2$, $W_1=\{(a,0): a\in \mathbb R\}$ and $W_2=\{(0,b): b \in \mathbb R\}$. I believe that this basic example would help you understand clearly what are going on.